# An ephemeral IP not assigned to the Load Balancer in GKE during service deployment

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-service

I'm trying to deploy service which looks like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    appName: {{ include "common.fullname" . }}
    componentName: config-service
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: config-service
  name: config-service
spec:
  ports:
    - name: "{{ .Values.app.ports.configService.port }}"
      port: {{ .Values.app.ports.configService.port }}
      targetPort: {{ .Values.app.ports.configService.port }}
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: config-service
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

but during the deployment to new project CI/CD pipeline will throw an error message

```
Service does not have load balancer ingress IP address: test/config-service
```

Based on similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53380452/how-can-i-create-kubernetes-load-balancer-with-an-ephemeral-ip-in-gke) it should to assign by default but for some reason it doesn't

Any thoughts on that?

PS.

Looks like one of the pods fail to start

```
Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is com.google.api.gax.rpc.PermissionDeniedException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied on resource project ${PROJECT_ID}.
```

which is weird as the whole project deployment uses the same `PROJECT_ID`

Comment: Does `config-service` actually get created?  `kubectl get services`

Comment: @GariSingh yes it does but there is a problem with a dependency which I have described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74159365/yaml-complaining-about-missing-element-when-is-present and may cause the whole deployment to stale and then force to uninstall (retract deployment)

Comment: Check for the quotas of the project, probably you hit the max number of forwarding rules

Comment: @ArnauSenserrich I have found the issue. OP updated

Comment: @GariSingh I have found an issue with another pod in that deployment which causing the whole problem. OP is updated.